# Angular using ngIf then EventEmitter won't work

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if, angular-event-emitter

In my application, there are two childs and one parent

child A pass object to child b

```
<app-temp-add [map]="selectedMap"></app-temp-add>
```

child B use *ngif to check the object is defined or not
then after click the button, passing the object

.html

```
<div *ngIf="map">
  <div>
    <label for="hero-name">name: </label>
    <input id="map-name" value="{{ map.name }}" />
    <div>
      <label for="hero-name">{{ map.address }}</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <button class="add-button" (click)="add(map)">Add to list</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

.ts

```
  @Input() map: any;
  @Output() newItemEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();

  add(map: any) {
    this.newItemEvent.emit(map);
  }
```

parent should get the object but it failed

.HTML

```
<app-temp-add (newItemEvent)="addItem($event)"></app-temp-add>
```

.ts

```
  addItem(newItem: any | undefined) {
    console.log("outout");
  }
```

after testing, *ngIf is the reason why this happened

but why? and how to solve this problem?

Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1ngoav?file=src/app/top-bar/top-bar.component.html)

Comment: Could your provide a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com) so we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: There is no `[map]`in the second snipped, there is no `(newItemEvent)` in the first snippet

Comment: @Motscha I've already add the stakblitz. Sorry took a bit of time, first time using stackblitz

Comment: @Antoniossss  sorry I don't quite know what you mean,  I think I'm too amateur...

Comment: What is the expected outcome of pressing those buttons ?

Comment: I change the stackblitz a little bit. There are two buttons, B and C, in topbar.html, they're using the same function, so I hope they'll get the same results. Which is getting log output1 when emit the variable and getting log output2 when receiving the variable.

Comment: by the way, why button C repeats again?